# How to copy list column value in other column using SharePoint designer workflow in Moss

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer

I cannot use visual studio here.
We have a list with columns "New Type" and "Old Type".
When user change/edits the value of "New Type" column then workflow should trigger email notification and value of "New Type" gets copied into "Old Type" column.

Answer (score 1):

You can not access the Before & after Properties of an item in SPD  Workflow.

Other option to find the change in value of "New Type" is to create one hidden Temp Column & When workflow started on new item created, store the current Item's "New Type" value into that column with delimated format.

Once the Item is update you can retrive the value of Temp column in the string variable, 
then use the

`If value equals value`

Use the above condition to determine whether the value has been changed or not, if it is changed then use the Sed Email activity to send mail and `Set feild in current item` to set the "Old Type" column value to current item's "New Type" value.

[Workflow conditions in SPD 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-designer-help/introduction-to-workflows-HA010100587.aspx#BM2)

To do string operation on the variable - Use below codeplex utility for accessing more function/methods for string operation.

http://spdwfstringactions.codeplex.com/